# Is there an implementation of silverlight's policy file server in twisted?

Tags: .net, python, silverlight, twisted

Is there an implementation for silverlight's xml policy file server in twisted python?
If not, what should I know to implement one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Twisted itself, no.  But all you need to know is how to [include static content](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.static.File.html) on your site.  If you're using a command like `twistd web --path foo`, just create a `foo/clientaccesspolicy.xml` (or `foo/crossdomain.xml`) and you are done.

Comment: But the policy file server is not an http server. It's a simple TCP server.

Comment: @Glyph: Hmm I think I get it now. I can use twistd web to serve files over tcp?

Comment: @Glyph: I just checked myself. It's served over http which isn't good for me.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx the policy file is requested via HTTP.  HTTP is on top of TCP; you can't serve "files" over just TCP.  Where is the protocol that you want to implement described?

Comment: @Glyph: "In Silverlight version 4 for a connection request using System.Net.Sockets, an application can choose instead to retrieve the policy file via the HTTP protocol on TCP port 80 instead of the custom TCP protocol on port 943." So, yeh I can just serve the file over a tcp socket but I can still use the twistd web interesting :)

Comment: "the custom TCP protocol" does not mean "TCP".  You would need to find out more details of that custom TCP protocol if you wanted to serve a file over it.  But luckily if you're using version 4, you don't have to ;).